# ffmpeg issue with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract frames from a video file using ffmpeg in Python.  I installed ffmpeg using Homebrew and ffmpeg-python on the Anaconda-Navigator.  Yet when I call ffmpeg on Jupyter notebook as follows

```
!ffmpeg -i "$file" "$rootdir"/"$folder_name"/frame%04d.png
```

I get an error saying

```
zsh:1: command not found: ffmpeg
```

I clearly see ffmpeg in my usr/local/bin.  Can someone please assist me in sorting this? I am able to use ffmpeg in Google Colab, though.

Comment: You seem to be mixing and matching a lot of different installation routes and package managers. In general that's a recipe for disaster. It sounds like you are using the Anaconda distribution on a Mac to launch Jupyter notebook so you should do you best to stick with installation methods in that ecosystem. Try in a cell inside the notebook where you want to run`!ffmpeg ...`, running first `%conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`, and then restarting the kernel and trying `!ffmpeg -h`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using `!/usr/bin/ffmpeg` was the solution, you can also verify this by trying `!whereis ffmpeg` and use whatever directory it's in after the `!` hope this helps!